# Is it possible that instead ContextMenuStrip of NotifyIcon, display a Form, which will behave like ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

I want to replace `ContextMenuStrip` of `NotifyIcon` with some more complex `Form`. I can display form when user click on NotifyIcon in SystemTray but I can't hide/close form like ContextMenuStrip close when user click somewhere else.

Is that possible?

Here is example code, I Show that form this way:

```
private void Mouse_Up_Event(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{  
    FormMenu f = new FormMenu();
    f.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
    f.SetDesktopLocation(Cursor.Position.X - f.Width / 2,
        Cursor.Position.Y - f.Height - 20);
    f.Show();
    f.Focus();
}
```

And `FormMenu` is a complex form with panels and multiple buttons.

Comment: I edited your question and deleted the parts that was not needed. Now the question is more readable:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host your complex control or form in `ContextMenuStrip` using [`ToolStripControlHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Code:**

```
var c= new MyUserControl();
//Set up properties and events then add it to context menu
this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(new ToolStripControlHost(c));
```

You can also add your form to context menu strip this way:

```
var f = new YourForm() { 
    TopLevel = false, 
    FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None, 
    MinimumSize= new Size(200, 200), /*Your preferred size*/
    Visible=true
};
//Set up properties and events then add it to context menu
this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(new ToolStripControlHost(f) );
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

In above screenshot I added a form to a context menu strip that has not other items and set `ShowImageMargin` property of context menu to `false`.

You can also have other Items and sub menus.